# How does TextX defines boundaries between words?

Tags: textx

Consider the following made up example with 3 rules.

Model: id_1=Ident 'is' id_2=Ident;

Keyword: 'is';

Ident: !Keyword ID;

It seems like TextX cannot parse inputs where id_2 starts with "is", e.g., "Tom is isolated".
I get the following error:
None:1:7: error: Expected Not at position ../test.txt:(1, 7) => 'Tom is* isolated'.
Why is that happening? Shouldn't "isolated" be considered as one word that is different from "is"? TextX can parse the input if id_2 does not start with "is".

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

textX doesn't assume by default that matching should be done on word boundaries. To solve your problem you can either define keywords to match on word boundaries like:

```
Keyword: /\bis\b/;
```

or use [auto keywords feature](http://textx.github.io/textX/stable/parser_config/#automatic-keywords) which can be turned on using `autokwd=True` in `metamodel_from_file/str` calls.